# WordPress creating non-unique GUIDs

Tags: php, wordpress, guid

Tried to activate a RSS Feed for my WP Site today. Running it through the W3C Feed Validator showed some posts had the same GUID. Upon Checking it, I saw that all newly created Posts had GUIDs looking like so:

https://example.de/blog//

instead of the expected

https://example.de/?p=2017

for example.

As I read about a thousand times now one should not change GUIDs manually so I don't really want to go into my phpMyAdmin and change them manually.

Anyone have an idea why this might happen and how to fix it?